# How to configure Kafka to have consumers and producers recover from failures when replication is disabled?

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, kafka-producer-api, apache-kafka-connect

We have a use case where data loss is acceptable(think 30-50% loss acceptable). In an effort to reduce costs, we want to know if it is possible to configure Kafka with a replication factor of 1 such that consumers and producer can recover from broker failures by simply consuming and producing from and to available partitions.

If this is possible, what are the configurations that need to be set?

There are other broker technologies that inherently behave this way, however, we would like to avoid the introduction of another technology as kafka is already part of our ecosystem.

Answer (score 2):

If you create a new topic via `bin/kafka-topics.sh` you need to specify parameter `--replication-factor`; just set it to `1` to disable replication.

For existing topics, you can change the replication factor using `bin/kafka/topics.sh` using parameter `--alter`.

For producers and consumers you might need to do some extra exception handling. For example, if you do specify a dedicated partition when you write a record and the broker is not reachable, you might need to take for of this (maybe just skip this write or whatever is appropriate). But there is no specific configuration you need to set for you clients.